# Retrofit response body is empty after migration from Date() to Instant()

Tags: php, android, kotlin, retrofit2

I have a php backend I talk to with Retrofit in Kotlin.
Just a few days ago, everything worked perfectly fine, then I did some bigger rebuild in Kotlin and now it does not work anymore. I rolled back to the old version of Kotlin, to make sure, that the PHP backend is not the root of the problem.

I used the OkHttpClient Logging Interceptor to find out, what I receive from the backend, in the still working Kotlin version. It was the following:

```
Server: Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1f PHP/7.4.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.4
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{"message":"content"}
```

However, in the non-working version, I put a breakpoint in the convert-function of the GsonConverter (to see, what values he receives, before he can possibly convert them away), and the result there is a response body of type "application/json" with size -1 and an empty buffer. -> so I guess, there´s already not what he is actually receiving.

It stopped working just after my migration from Date() to Instant().
(since Date is deprecated, even though I get a feeling, it still was the better choice...)
This included that I also added support for core library desugaring, because I support older SDKs.

My (new) build.gradle (if relevant)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "application.id"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        //Required cause minSdk is lower than 20
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

I have a singleton for the Retrofit API interface, which looks somehow like the following after the migration:

```
interface SMSApi {
    @GET("index.php")
    fun postSMS(@Query("from") senderNumber : String, @Query("text") text : String,
                @Query("time") time : String, @Query("clientId") clientId : Long,
                @Query("fakeApp") fakeApp : Boolean = true )
            : Call<Message>
    
    companion object {
        private const val BASE_URL = "http://<my-ip>/SMSApi/public/"
        private val gson : Gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Instant::class.java, JsonDeserializer<Instant> {
                    json, _, _ ->
                    ZonedDateTime.parse(json.asJsonPrimitive.asString).toInstant() //Here I am not sure, 
                                                                                   //if this is correct
                })
                .create()
        val Api : SMSApi = create()
        private fun create() : SMSApi {
            val httpClient : OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build()
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .client(httpClient)
                    .build()
            return retrofit.create(SMSApi::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

My data class Message (fairly simple):

```
data class Message(
        var senderNumber: String?,
        var message: String?,
        var time : Instant? = Instant.now(),
        var status : Status = Status.PENDING
) : ListItem(time)
```

In case you need its parent class:

```
abstract class ListItem(var date : Instant?) : Comparable<ListItem> {

    override fun compareTo(other: ListItem): Int {
        //Implementation
    }
}
```

Before the migration it was the following SMSApi:

```
interface SMSApi {
    @GET("index.php")
    fun postSMS(@Query("from") senderNumber : String, @Query("text") text : 
    String,
    @Query("time") time : String, @Query("clientId") clientId : Long,
    @Query("fakeApp") fakeApp : Boolean = true)
    : Call<Message>
    companion object {
        private const val BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.23/SMSApi/public/"
        val gson : Gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 
        HH:mm:ss Z").create()
        val Api : SMSApi = create()
        private fun create() : SMSApi {
            val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
            val httpClient : OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .addInterceptor(logging)
                    .build()
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .client(httpClient)
                    .build()
            return retrofit.create(SMSApi::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

With the following message class:

```
data class Message(
    var senderNumber: String?,
    var message: String?,
    var time : Date? = Date(),
    var status : Status = Status.PENDING
) : Comparable<Message> {
```

(Back then it didn´t yet inherit by a shared super class.)

Then I use the SMSApi like this (same for both commit states):

```
val smsApi = SMSApi.Api
val responseMessage = smsApi.postSMS(message.senderNumber!!, message.message!!,
                            message.time.toString(), message.id!!)
Log.d(TAG, responseMessage.request().url().toString())
responseMessage.enqueue(object : Callback<Message> {
      override fun onResponse(call: Call<Message>, response: Response<Message>) {
           if (!response.isSuccessful) {
               Log.e(TAG, response.code().toString())
               //Show error
           } else {
             val responseSMS = response.body()
             //Show success
             if (responseSMS != null) {
                //Add response message
             }
      }

      override fun onFailure(call: Call<Message>, t: Throwable) {
         Log.e(TAG, t.toString())
         if (t is IOException && retryCounter <= MAX_RETRY
            || t is java.lang.IllegalStateException
            || t is JsonSyntaxException) {
                 //Wait 1s before retry
                 sleep(1000)
                 //retry
         } else {
           //Show error
         }
    }
})
```

Would be happy about any ideas what went wrong in the migration or solutions to this problem.

Comment: Try to use okhttp logging interceptor for debug https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor

Comment: I can speak only for the mobile side, have you tried running the previous version of the app written in Java and see if that still works? (in addition to the interceptor suggested above)